# Initialise class without instantiate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods

I'm trying to work on a simple class that fills in some lists and then tries to retrieve that information back, something like:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.src = []
        self.values = []

    def addItems(self, name, val):
        self.src.append(name)
        self.values.append(val)

    def getItem(self, item):
        for i, x in enumerate(self.src):
            if x == item:
                return self.src[i], self.values[i]
```

To use this class, I first have to instanciate it, `Foo()`, and only then start adding and retrieving objects.

```
a = Foo()
a.addItems('A', '1')
a.addItems('B', '2')
a.src  # ['A', 'B']
a.values  # ['1', '2']
a.getItem('A')  # ('A', '1')
```

Is there any way to add the elements without having to initialise the class first? Something like `Foo.addItems('A', '1')`(this gives a `TypeError: addItems() missing 1 required positional argument: 'val'`).

I saw other related posts using `@staticmethod`, but couldn't figure out how to make it work in this example.

Comment: What's the actual purpose of your trying not to instantiate a class?

Comment: This class is supposed to be used several times as part of a larger program, so I guess that not having to instanciate it every time is called would be favourable, for example to avoid these kinds of repetition: `x = Foo() ... y = Foo() ... z = Foo()`

Comment: If you have to repetitively instantiate the class several times in a similar way you should use a loop to instantiate them as a dict or list of objects.

Comment: I see, that could be an option, but instead of making the main program more complex, was wondering if this could be better accomplished at the class level itself. And I guess it would also need an assignment every time: `x = list_holding_instantiated_class[0] ... y = list_holding_instantiated_class[1]`.

Comment: No, instances are meant to accomplish exactly what you're looking for. Trying to manage attribute values of different instances of a class without actually creating instances defeats the very purpose of a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you have in mind. I guess you may get something close to what you have described. Two steps are needed.

First - create module, say, `foo_module`, where you create and instantiate your class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.src = []
        self.values = []
    def addItems(self, name, val):
        self.src.append(name)
        self.values.append(val)
    def getItem(self, item):
        for i, x in enumerate(self.src):
            if x == item:
                return self.src[i], self.values[i]

root_foo = Foo()
src = root_foo.src
values = root_foo.values

def addItems(*args):
    return root_foo.addItems(*args)

def getItem(*args):
    return root_foo.getItem(*args)
```

Second - import `foo_module` and use it:

```
import foo_module as f_m

f_m.addItems('A', '1')
f_m.addItems('B', '2')
print(f_m.getItem('A'))
print(f_m.src)
print(f_m.values)
```

Now you access the same `Foo` instance any time you access `foo_module` across all your scripts. By the way, it's how python `logging` module works (root logger).

Comment: Awesome, this is very close to what I was looking for.